# Is the RT Linux kernel monolithic or a micro-kernel (like QNX)?

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, real-time, qnx

I am studying some documents regarding RT linux and qnx and confused about monolithic and microkernel.Some papers are telling that RT linux is monolithic and some are saying that microkernel. I am worried which is right ?? could you please some one answer my question ??

I know QNX is a microkernel Os and confused w.r.t RTlinunx.
Could someone tell me what is the differenec between the two real time operating system and also the below question.
RT linux is monolithic or microkernel ??

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, there is no actual RT Linux<sup>1</sup>. There are only approaches of adding RT compatibily features² to the official genereal purpose Linux kernel. Examples are [RTAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTAI), [Xenomai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenomai) or the [PREEMPT_RT patch](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). Thus, they're all using the same kernel which is definitely a monolithic kernel (and as for Linus this will pretty sure stay this way).

However, a [paper](http://www.sersc.org/journals/IJCA/vol6_no1/20.pdf)³ by Jae Hwan Koh and Byoung Wook Cho about RTAI and Xenomai performance evaluation puts it like this (which indeed sounds more like a separate kernel approach):

> RTAI and Xenomai are interfaces for real-time tasks rather than real-time operating systems. Therefore, an OS is needed to use them; Linux is most widely used. In RTAI and Xenomai, the Linux OS kernel is treated as an idle task, and it only executes when there are no real-time tasks to run. The figure below shows the architectures and versions of the real-time embedded Linux used [here]. RTAI and Xenomai are conceptually homogeneous, and they both use a general-purpose Linux kernel and real-time API. However, there is a remarkable contrast.. [in way they handle certain things].

[image: Graphical comparison of the kernel extensions]
Another picture that if found⁴ supports this point-of-view as well, i.e. having a kernel running on-top of another one as idle task.
[image: General RT Linux plugin approach]

---

<sup>1 Having said that, there used to be a OS (kernel) named [RTLinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTLinux) which was working quite similar like the other approaches mentioned in my answer above, ie it runs the entire Linux kernel as a fully preemptive process [[1](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/realtime/restricted/notes/rtlinux.html)] [[2](http://www.yodaiken.com/papers/BarabanovThesis.pdf)]. RTLinux later merged into the products of Wind River (VxWorks) and did also influenced the work around [RTAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTAI). Couldn't find a source about the kernel type.</sup>

<sup>2 in other words a "real-time extension"</sup> 
 <sup>3 "Real-time Performance of Real-time Mechanisms for RTAI and Xenomai in Various Running Conditions", 2013, International Journal of Control and Automation</sup>

<sup>4 unfortunately I could not determine its source yet.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

RT Linux has both linux kernel as well as real time kernel. The real time kernel has higher priority over linux kernel. Please refer following article for details.

http://www.cs.ru.nl/~hooman/DES/RealtimeLinuxBasics.pdf

Comment: While the term "RT-Linux" usually means realtime patch for mainline linux.